# Is any Atom data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When I read/show `String` I get/expect the result to be quoted. If I want to omit quotes, I can implement some type like:

```hs
newtype Atom = Atom String deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance Read Atom where ...
instance Show Atom where ...
```

But my question is: does such type already exist somewhere in libraries, in the base, may be? I just found some `Data.Atom` but seems it something different (XML, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** If you find yourself wanting this, it means you're using `Show` in an unintended way. The idea of `show` is that is should *always yield valid Haskell code*. The `Show String` instance guarantees this, by safely quoting and escaping the contents. Short of that, you would of course in general *not* get Haskell code. Now, sure there are applications where you want to display something and don't care about whether it's Haskell code, but that shouldn't be `show` then.

Usually, if you have a string anyway, you should just use `putStrLn` directly.

Comment: hm, may be you are write about "always yield valid Haskell code". But if I need to read anything which can be read PLUS such atom, if I'll follow those requirement then I should create own type class or to produce other boilerplate code... Interesting dilemma.

Comment: Well, if you know you'll have `String` values then you don't need any typeclass at all, just pass the strings right away. If you have values of different type and want to display them really compactly, then `String` as the output type is likely not practical anyway, you should look into something that generates HTML or LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Read` and `Show` are for converting data to/from strings, you can just use the `id` function :)

But seriously, a String is already the output of its own `read` or `show`, if you don't want it quoted.

Say, for example, to print any other value (or a String, if you want it to appear quoted), you do:

```hs
putStrLn (show "Hello") -- prints "Hello", with quotes.
```

whereas, to print a string unquoted, you can simply do:

```hs
putStrLn "Hello" -- prints Hello, unquoted.
```

Because of this, I don't think there is any utility for this (it is trivial, after all); in fact, your Atom instances would simply be:

```hs
instance Read Atom where read = Atom
instance Show Atom where show (Atom s) = s
```

Comment: `where read = Atom`... more probably `readsPrec` because `read` is not visible method of 'Read'. OK, utility is not to put such value to the console/file but to read string/line without quotes, so it seems strange that Haskell has not such type, it's typical for most FP languages, except Haskell

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to inspect the type and use `print` for non-strings and `putStrLn` for strings like this:

```hs
import Data.Typeable

printAny :: (Show a, Typeable a) => a -> IO ()
printAny a = case cast a of
  Just str -> putStrLn str
  Nothing  -> print a
```

Then, as desired:

```
*Main> printAny "no quotes"
no quotes
*Main> printAny (10 :: Int)
10
```